# Templatedoesnot exist django

Tags: python, django, templates

enter image description here I'm currently taking an online course on django, and am working right now in part 3 where we deal with templates I followed the instructions but every time I go to `mysite/polls`,
I get 'no template exist' error.
This is my polls/view.py.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Question

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import Http404



def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
def owner(request):
 return HttpResponse("Hello, world. 9d5a197b is the polls index.")

def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

/polls/urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('owner', views.owner, name='owner'),

]
```

mysite/settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-)_f&roo%#9%s$7&0vjlz@7%k!4q!^jnkc4(vle(xi78u48at@s'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },


]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

My index.html is at
polls/templates/polls.
Every time I go to python anywhere to show sitename/polls,
I get this error. I have tried a lot of solutions,
but am not an expert on django, so please help me. I still have 5 days left to submit my assignment.

```
/home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/1narjess/django_projects/mysite/polls/views.py, line 15, in index
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py, line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
/home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 61, in render_to_string
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
/home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain) …
▶ Local vars
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO4l3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add **templates**  *-Which is the directory that has your HTML pages-*  to **DIRS**.

It will look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: @Narjess okay try adding your app **polls** at the bottom of *INSTALLED_APPS*

Comment: everytime i try this i got
Something went wrong :-(
This website is hosted by PythonAnywhere, an online hosting environment. Something went wrong while trying to load it; please try again later.

Answer (score 0):

first of you have to tell django in your setting.py a path for where to look for templates for that in you project

in your settings.py type path

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'templates'
```

and then in

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

pass your template path like this in your template settings and after that create a folder name template in in same folder wher manage.py exits and copy paste all your template there
and then you will be good to go on
and tell me if you still got any error

Comment: i tried this but i still get the same error

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
polls/index.html

Comment: django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/1narjess/django_projects/mysite/templates/polls/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/polls/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/1narjess/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/polls/index.html (Source does not exist)

Comment: am not working locally since am working on python anywhere to get my grade

Comment: add the screenshot of your working directory and also add the complete traceback

Comment: @Narjess it doesnt matter for template in local mode or production mode it always look for the path which you provide it to look for

Comment: i add my traceback at the end of my question

Comment: i add my screenshot too in enter image description here am not allowed to post picture yet i dont know if it will show

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/ polls/index.html it seems django is lookin your template in that path /polls/ polls/index.html but it has to be  polls/index.html

Comment: according to the tutorial i have to put it polls/templates/polls/index.html